# Azure Functions v2 Connectionstring from application settings

Tags: function, azure, connection-string

I have made a simple Azure Functions v2 Web Service that connects to an Azure SQL database, runs a stored procedure with 3 parameters and returns the result as JSON output. It works as it is now (with the connectionstring in the run.csx file).

But how do I get it to get the connectionstring from Applications Settings?

I have tried various guides both here and other places. But all I can find is a long list of references and a whole bunch of code I need to add. I have followed the guides to the letter (also set the values in App Settings), but it just wont work. I'm rather new to C#, so it might be I just don't understand what I'm supposed to do.

Anyways this is my code and the suggested fix, as far as I'm able to tell:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "System.Data"
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public static async Task<ActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
   log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

   string login = req.Query["login"];
   string pwd = req.Query["password"];
   string TransID = req.Query["TransID"];

   string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
   dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
   login = login ?? data?.login;
   pwd = pwd ?? data?.password;
   TransID = TransID ?? data?.TransID;

   var cnnString = "Server=MyServer;Database=WebServices;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;Encrypt=True;";

        try
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetRegRW", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Login", login));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", pwd));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TransID", TransID));
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(table);
            }

            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table));
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"The following SqlException happened: {sqlex.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"The following Exception happened: {ex.Message}");
        }

}
```

suggested solution:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "System.Data"
#r "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration"
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

public static async Task<ActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
   var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

   var cnnString =config.GetConnectionString("connWS");
   var setting1 = config["Setting1"];

   log.LogInformation(cnnString);
   log.LogInformation(setting1);
   log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

   string login = req.Query["login"];
   string pwd = req.Query["password"];
   string TransID = req.Query["TransID"];

   string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
   dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
   login = login ?? data?.login;
   pwd = pwd ?? data?.password;
   TransID = TransID ?? data?.TransID;

        try
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_GetRegRW", connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Login", login));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", pwd));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TransID", TransID));
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(table);
            }

            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table));
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"The following SqlException happened: {sqlex.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"The following Exception happened: {ex.Message}");
        }

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup#get-connection-information

Comment: thanks for the link Brad. I didn't code it in VS locally and publish it. I just typed the code directly in the online editor. I have added the ADO.net connectionstring from the DB to application parameters and called it connWS. when I call the connectionstring as suggested (var cnnString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("connWS");) I get the following error: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In function v2, you should use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("string_name",EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)` to get values from Application settings and connection strings.

**Note**: When use the above method, the first parameter depends on the Type. It means that when the type of the connection string is `SQLAZURE`, then the first parameter should be `SQLAZURE + CONNSTR + _stringName`.

The screenshot is as below: [image]

The code sample:

```
//for connection string
string connStr = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_sqldb_connection",EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
log.LogInformation("the connection string is: " + connStr);
```

And the result snapshot:

[image]

> I get the following error: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

You should probably create an instance of SqlConnection, **with your connection string and open this connection before try to make any command**.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connStr");
await con.OpenAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you Joey! all I needed was the prefix to the connectionstring-name (SQLAZURECONNSTR_). now it runs smoothly. Funny i never saw anything about it, anywhere else I have looked.